# Find maximal element from range operations

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm

Starting with a zero array `A` of size `N`, we perform a series of `K` operations on each element given a list of range queries of the form `add(A[i, j], k)` (`i <= j` and `k > 0`) - that is, for each element in the subarray `A[i, j]`, add the value `k`.  After all of these range queries are applied, find the maximal value in the array.

This is trivial to do by constructing an array, evaluating each query, and finding the maximum.  For instance,

```
A = [0 for _ in range(N)]

for i, j, k in queries:
    for idx in range(i, j + 1):
        A[idx] += k

max(A) # Solution
```

But this solution has complexity `O(NK)`, which for large `N` and `K` is rather slow.  Is there a better solution?  I have been looking into segment trees as a possible method, but cannot see a clear approach.

Comment: Sort the range endpoints and sweep from the left, adding when you hit the start of a range and subtracting when you hit the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
A = [0] * (N + 1)

for i, j, k in queries:
    A[i] += k
    A[j + 1] -= k

v, m = 0, 0
for k in A:
    v += k
    m = max(m, v)

return m
```

This is `O(N + K)` time and `O(N)` memory

Comment: This may have an off by one error and `A` should be expanded to `[0] * (N+1)`, depending on if your definition of `subarray A[i, j]` is inclusive or exclusive of `j`

Comment: It is inclusive - see ranges in problem statement: A[i, i] is valid

Comment: Thanks @Knio, that makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Note: if `N >> K`, you can improve this algorithm to `O(K log K)` by storing the elements `(i, v)` of `A` in a heap/tree/etc

Comment: You probably meant A[j + 1] -= k